# Cordova Google Plus Plugin Error 10

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, google-plus

**I want to use google plus auth in my cordova android app.**

**1. Create app**

```
cordova create testapp com.test.android TestApp
```

**2. Add android platform**

```
cordova platform add android
```

**3. Add google plus plugin**

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus@5.1.1
```

**4. Build app**

```
cordova build android
```

**5. Get sha1 hash from debugkeystore**

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
sha1 hash: 7A:4A:F7:57:F5:B4:FC:F9:A5:49:D0:1D:26:4B:BC:7F:46:9C:F3:BC
```

**6. Create new project in:**

```
https://console.firebase.google.com/
```

**7. Add android app in firebase:**

```
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/my-project/overview
package name: com.test.android
sha1 hash: 7A:4A:F7:57:F5:B4:FC:F9:A5:49:D0:1D:26:4B:BC:7F:46:9C:F3:BC
```

**8. Google generated credentials:**

```
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=my-project

Name: Android client for com.test.android (auto created by Google Service)
ClientID: 512345670038-vpas878tase55aemtb2asd4tmj6liasd.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

**9. My app code**

```
window.plugins.googleplus.getSigningCertificateFingerprint(
    function (fingerprint) {
        alert(fingerprint); // 7A:4A:F7:57:F5:B4:FC:F9:A5:49:D0:1D:26:4B:BC:7F:46:9C:F3:BC
    }
);

window.plugins.googleplus.login(
    {
        'scopes': '',
        'webClientId': '512345670038-vpas878tase55aemtb2asd4tmj6liasd.apps.googleusercontent.com', // ClientID
        'offline': true,
    },
    function (obj) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
    },
    function (msg) {
        alert('error: ' + msg); // I always get error 10
    }
);
```

**I am always get error: 10**

What am i doing wrong? Can anybody help me... I try to use this plugin in existing project, but it doesn't work... I created empty cordova android project... But it's doesn't work too... Please, help me...